# Get Value From Json object contain table column using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a table `Books` with two columns `Id`, `BookCategory` in a SQL Server database, where `Id` is the primary key and `BookCategory` contains JSON object.

This my table [Books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6X1B.png)

I'm trying to get table `BookCategory` column value as `Category` only. For that, I wrote the following SQL query but I didn't get. any have an idea about to get JSON object value as the normal column value as a query result.

```
SELECT 
    Id, BookCategory.Name AS Name, 
    BookCategory.Category AS Category 
FROM
    Books
```

So the result will look like :

```
Id=1
Name=CA
Category=cs
```

And I'm getting an error in SQL Server Management Studio:

> The multi-part identifier "BookCategory.Name" could not be bound.

Any help to get result same of the above table Books.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It should be

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    JSON_VALUE(BookCategory,'$.Name') AS Name, 
    JSON_VALUE(BookCategory,'$.Category') AS Category 
FROM
    Books
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

You need to use special functions to work with JSON in SQL (JSON is supported in MS-SQL 2016). `Table.column` notation is for regular SQL column types like `INTEGER` or `VARCHAR` etc.

Comment: @Dmity, I need to display Name and Category as empty if BookCategory is invalid json or empty. How do I do that? I tried the below query but there is some mismatch in count SELECT Id, JSON_VALUE(ProgressJson,'$.ActualTIme') AS actualtime, JSON_VALUE(ProgressJson,'$.CurrentTIme') AS currenttime FROM [ProgressInstances] pi WHERE  ProgressJson = CASE WHEN ISJSON(pi.ProgressJson) > 0 THEN ProgressJson ELSE '{}' END

Comment: @Dmitry, using many JSON_VALUE-s in query harm performance or not ? for example If json in column have many parameters, will It harm performance or not to write JSON_VALUE for each parameter ? Thanks in advance. Maybe there is serialization for each json_value query ?

Answer (score 2):

You can select multiple values from a json column with `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT 
    BookId = b.Id, 
    BookTitle = b.Title,
    CategoryId = c.Id,
    c.Category, 
    CategoryName = c.Name
FROM Books b
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (b.BookCategory) WITH -- BookCategory is the json column
    (
        Id INT,
        Category VARCHAR(100),
        [Name] VARCHAR(100)
    ) c
```

If you like, you can rename columns selected during the `CROSS APPLY`. This has the same result as above.

```
SELECT 
    BookId = b.Id, 
    BookTitle = b.Title,
    c.CategoryId,
    c.Category, 
    c.CategoryName
FROM Books b
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (b.BookCategory) WITH
    (
        CategoryId INT '$.Id',
        Category VARCHAR(100),
        CategoryName VARCHAR(100) '$.Name'
    ) c
```

You can also select nested properties from objects in a `CROSS APPLY`.  Suppose your `BookCategory` also included a Location:

`{ Id: 1, Name: CA, Category: cs, Location: { Building: Main, Floor: 2, Shelf: 4F }}`

You can include Building like:

```
SELECT 
    BookId = b.Id, 
    BookTitle = b.Title,
    c.CategoryId,
    c.Category, 
    c.CategoryName, 
    c.Building
FROM Books b
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (b.BookCategory) WITH
    (
        CategoryId INT '$.Id',
        Category VARCHAR(100),
        CategoryName VARCHAR(100) '$.Name',
        Building VARCHAR(100) '$.Location.Building'
    ) c
```